# How to configure sonata user bundle

Tags: mongodb, symfony, composer-php, sonata-admin, sonata-user-bundle

Alter update composer requirements got error

> ServiceNotFoundException: The service "sonata.user.serializer.handler.user" has a dependency on a non-existent service "sonata.user.manager.user".

How to fix it?

Answer (score 4):

In services.yml setup serializer service:

```
services:
    sonata.user.serializer.handler.user:
        class: Sonata\UserBundle\Serializer\UserSerializerHandler
        tags:
            - { name: jms_serializer.subscribing_handler }
        arguments:
            - [ sonata.user.mongodb.user_manager ]
```

It's need if you use MongoDb - seriaziler have default settings for ORM

Comment: I'd like to know where in the documentation you have found that. Because I was following the docs and it is not there in a easy way.

Comment: It is still not mentioned in the documentation. I have corrected the yml-syntax.

Answer (score 1):

You can also write this code in config/config.yml:

```
services:
sonata.user.serializer.handler.user:
class: Sonata\UserBundle\Serializer\UserSerializerHandler
tags:
- { name: jms_serializer.subscribing_handler }
arguments:
- [ sonata.user.mongodb.user_manager ]
```